# Trying to create a list within a list for my netcdf dataset

Tags: r, for-loop, netcdf

I am very new to R and currently working a large amount of NARR netcdf files for my project.
Initially I tried to merge all of them so that I only deal with one file but trying to convert them from 3d to 2d array using that one big file takes up almost 64gb of ram.
Due to the limitation of my ram, I was advised to loop through multiple netcdf files (200mb) each instead of extracting information from the merged file (33gb).

My goal is to extract the variable (e.g., convective available potential energy (CAPE)) for particular sets of coordinates. I have used over() function from rgdal library and successfully retrieved the indices.
Below is the code to extract indices per shapefile and saved them into a list (all_ind).

```
can_coor <- #csv file with NARR coordinates
coordinates(can_coor) <-~ Lon + Lat # to make them into spatial points

get_ind <- function(x){
  x <- readOGR(x) 
  
  proj4string(can_coor) <- proj4string(x) #to have consistent projection
  
  tor_ind <- over(x, can_coor)
  
}

files <- list.files(filepath,  pattern = ".shp$", full.names = T, all.files = F)

all_ind <- lapply(files, get_ind)
```

Next I am trying to apply each set of lon and lat indices all_ind[[i]] on the netcdf file to extract values from all time stamp for that particular coordinates and saved them in a new list.

Since I have limitation on my ram, I am planning to create a loop to read each netcdf file, and then extract all values for those indices and saved them into a separate list. So in the end, my list will have [[1:30]] (for 30 netcdf files), and within that [[1:30]], I will have [[1:239]] (for 239 sets of indices I am extracting).

I have come up with the following for loop but I am not sure how to fix it to get the desired results.

```
var_list <- list()
for(i in 1:length(all_ind)){
  fileL <- list.files("netcdf file path", pattern = ".nc$", full.names = T, all.files = F)
  n <- nc_open(fileL)
  for (j in 1:length(n)) {
    data <- ncvar_get(n, "cape")
    data <- matrix(data, dim(data)[3],dim(data)[1]*dim(data)[2]) #time as rows for easier filtration
    subset_data <- data[,all_ind[[i]]]
    var_list[[i]] <- subset_data
  }
 all_var_list[[i]] <- var_list
}
```

Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: may i suggest the `disk.frame` library? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/disk.frame/readme/README.html it is a more long term solution

Comment: @D.J I just read the description and it might be what I needed. Thank you so much I will look more into it!